# vba - regex parse currency or replace many spaces

Tags: regex, vba, parsing

This is the input:

> 1 22 333 4 asdaf44 1 400,00 4 12 1 400,00 767 4 800 100,24 2 100,88 55 3,00 555,90

And I want the following output:

> 1 22 333 4 asdaf44 1400,00 4 12 1400,00 767 4800100,24 2100,88 55 3,00 555,90

with:

```
    1 400,00 ->    1400,00
4 800 100,24 -> 4800100,24
    2 100,88 ->    2100,88
```

My solution is

```
/(?: )(\d{1,3})? ?(\d{3})? ?(\d{3})(?=,)/gm
```

replace with  *" $1$2$3"*

Is there a better regex pattern to handle the following output ?

> 9 999 999 999 999,10

to

> 9999999999999,10

So format is

```
     #,##
    ##,##
   ###,##
 # ###,## 
## ###,##
   ...
```

**EDIT**

Second solution(modified @Tim Pietzcker answer):

> ([^\s\d]\d{1,3} +)(?=(?:\d{3})+)|\b(\d{1,3}) +(?=(?: *\d{3})+,\d\d(?![\S]))

replace with "$1$2"

Left part of pattern(before "|") matching what we don't need to match in the right part. Looks like not True solution.

And it is not checking this situations:

```
0 100,00      //will be concatenated (0100,00)
```

[test on regex101.com](http://regex101.com/r/zO2fK5/5)

Answer (score 1):

**Edit:**

With the additional test case that fails when using the solution I originally posted (see below), I also think that a single regex isn't going to work, considering VBA's limited regex feature set.

You could try doing it in two steps:

First match all the relevant numbers using the regex `/\b\d{1,3}(?: \d{3})*,\d{2}\b/g` and then use a [callback function](http://cwestblog.com/2011/07/18/vbscript-regexp-replace-using-a-callback-function/) to remove all the spaces *within those matches*.

---

**Previous solution**:

Search for

```
\b(\d{1,3}) +(?=(?: *\d{3})*,)
```

and replace with `$1`:

```js
subject = "1 22 333 4 asdaf44 1 400,00 4 12 1 400,00 767 4 800 100,24 2 100,88 55 3,00";
result = subject.replace(/\b(\d{1,3}) +(?=(?: *\d{3})*,)/g, "$1");
alert(result);
```

**Explanation:**

```
\b         # Start of a number
(\d{1,3})  # Match 1-3 digits, capture in group $1
[ ]+       # Match one or more spaces
(?=        # only if followed by
 (?:       # the following group
  [ ]*     # which consists of any number of spaces
  \d{3}    # and three digits in succession
 )*        # repeated any number of times,
 ,         # immediately followed by a comma
)          # End of lookahead
```

Comment: Note that this answer is in JavaScript, but the regex still applies when you adapt it to your solution.

Comment: @nhahtdh: I thought VBA was a variant of ECMAScript - shouldn't this code run as-is?

Comment: I have seen VBScript (likely what the OP is using), and it is not anywhere the same as ECMAScript. I'm not entirely sure whether your code would run when you use it for VBA, though.

Comment: By the way, there is a potential backtracking problem here `) +(?=(?: *`. Repeated space followed by repeated space.

Comment: @nhahtdh: Interesting. I've managed to steer clear of VBA/VBScript so far :). You're right about the backtracking, although it's probably not too bad (and VBA/JS have neither atomic groups nor possessive quantifiers to avoid this problem).

Comment: tested. but this "1,00 333,10" going to be "1,00333,10" *added to question

Comment: @befzz: Right, that case isn't covered, and VBA's meager set of regex features makes it hard to work around that (lookbehind assertions would come in rather handy just about now). I'll try to think of something.

Comment: @Tim Pietzcker thank you for answer. And thats why i asked this question. with one .replace its seems impossible. :(